# Update Volley Cacheing in background

Tags: java, android, caching, android-volley

I have added a volley caching in Android for 15 mins on a specific page.

So whenever user comes on that page before 15 mins, he can see cached data. Now I want that if user comes after 15 mins also, he should see the same data and volley should send a new request to fetch new data in background (only when user opens that page after 15 mins).

If I get a valid data, then volley should update caching with new data else old caching should work.

Comment: Check 7.2 Invalidate cache, 7.4 Deleting cache for particular URL, 7.5 Deleting all the cache  to see how its done http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: Thanks a lot. This will work.

Comment: Please add your answer in comment with code snippets, for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Just it is my idea, Trickly you can achieve this by doing a datetime milliseconds validations, keep track on the current time milliseconds to the preference or any server location to achieve this one.